Proxychains4 and Tor
this is my first question so I will do my best to make it good. It's a bit of a doozy. I have seen other people ask about the same issue but they did not get this far in their troubleshooting.
I am on Ubuntu 22.04.4
My goal was to learn about proxychains4 and tor.
I successfully downloaded proxychains4 and tor with the following commands:
sudo apt install proxychains4
sudo apt install tor

And made the following configurations to my proxychains4.conf file:
random_chain
#
# Random - Each connection will be done via random proxy
# (or proxy chain, see  chain_len) from the list.
# this option is good to test your IDS :)

and
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
socks4  127.0.0.1 9050
socks5  127.0.0.1 9050

Then, I activated tor with
sudo service tor start

and, after trying the following:
proxychains4 firefox
proxychains firefox
proxychains4 firefox www.duckduckgo.com
proxychains firefox www.duckduckgo.com

I came up with the following out errors:
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains4.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.4
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
Gtk-Message: 22:01:21.421: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.

The error is right here in this line:
Gtk-Message: 22:01:21.421: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.

After a little bit of research, a potential solution was found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75406844/not-loading-module-atk-bridge-the-functionality-is-provided-by-gtk-natively
Which said to change the GTK_MODULES environment from
GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge

to
GTK_MODULES=firefox

which produced a new error
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains4.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.4
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
Gtk-Message: 22:04:30.803: Failed to load module "firefox"

here is the new error:
Gtk-Message: 22:04:30.803: Failed to load module "firefox"

and two different sources:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534129/opencv-error-gtk-2-x-symbols-detected-using-gtk-2-x-and-gtk-3-in-the-same-p
and
What does "Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected." mean?
state that there might be an issue where one of the apps I am launching (firefox, in this case I think; but could also be proxychains4)
uses GTK3.x and is simultaneously pulling GTK2.x libraries, causing the particular error I'm experiencing.
What is it that I need to do in order to be able to successfully run proxychains and tor using firefox? I have also tried it with brave and had a similar failure regarding GTK and a few other errors. (If interested I can post another question with the specifics surrounding the error messages when using brave).
It seems like I need to change some libraries or something. I am new to computer science and this was as far as I was able to get. If anyone needs more info, lmk and I will do my best to provide. Also, I extensively checked out tor and am confident that tor is not the issue. It seems to me to be either proxychains4 or firefox that is having this issue.
After running
firefox

by itself, it seems like firefox is producing the result.
Whenever I check whatismyip it always returns my actaul ip and not the proxy.
Thanks!
-pumpkinetchers
